# Type inference in Tuple.Create way

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm having a hard time understanding why type inference is not working. I have VS2010 (C# 4.0)

Please consider sample code:

```
public interface IMapping<TRecord> { }

static class DateMapping // Trying to mimic Tuple.Create here
{
    public static IMapping<TRecord> Make<TRecord>()
    {
        return null;
    }
}

class DateMapping<TRecord, TReturn> : IMapping<TRecord>
{
    public DateMapping(Func<TRecord, TReturn> x)
    {

    }
}

public static class MappingHelper
{
    public static List<IMapping<TRecord>> MakeMappings<TRecord>(this IEnumerable<TRecord> data, IMapping<TRecord> m1)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var data = new[]
        {
            new {a = 1, b = 2},
            new {a = 1, b = 2}
        };

       // The type arguments for method 'TypeInference.MappingHelper.MakeMappings<TRecord>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TRecord>, TypeInference.IMapping<TRecord>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.  c:\repo\TypeInference\TypeInference\Program.cs
        var mappings = data.MakeMappings(DateMapping.Make());
    }
}
```

I'm not and an expert in C# type system. Could you please help me find a way to make my sample working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DateMapping.Make() has no parameters from which the compiler could infer the type, so you have to specify it explicitly (or add a TRecord parameter to the method).

Explicit type parameter (will not work with anonymous type):

```
var data = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
var mappings = data.MakeMappings(DateMapping.Make<int>());
```

TRecord parameter in the method:

```
static class DateMapping
{
    public static IMapping<TRecord> Make<TRecord>(TRecord record)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
//...
var data = new[] 
{
    new {a = 1, b = 2},
    new {a = 1, b = 2}
};

var mappings = data.MakeMappings(DateMapping.Make(new { a = 1, b = 2 }));
```

Comment: For some reason I thought that type inference may work in opposite way.